# How to make the asterisk(*) in <TextValidator> float to right?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

I'm using TextValidator from 'react-material-ui-form-validator' and Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
and I have multiple fields to compress in a single row.

[ReactJS UI - TextValidator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngU92.jpg)

I know I can shorten the label description to solve my problem, however I can't.

```js
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
                    <TextValidator
                        required
                        id="AbcdefKey"                
                        name="AbcdefKey"
                        validators={['required', 'isPositive']}
                        errorMessages={['this field is required','Must be numeric and greater than zero']}                
                        fullWidth
                        value="1111"          
                        label="AbcdefKey"
                    />  
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you state what you expect from the working code and what happens instead? It is not clear from the question

Comment: Hi @beniutek, I want to make the asterisk float to the right of the label. If you could view the screenshot I hope it can make more sense.